# IndexOn on firebase Root to query entire database swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to query by name inside firebase database, I want to return all the names matching the query. But I can't seem to get it to work, I am getting error **Consider adding ".indexOn": "name" at / to your security rules**.

Security Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true",
    "goals_new": {
      ".indexOn": ["name"]
    }
  }
}
```

I Can retrieve the names for specific child like this:

```
let query = ref.child("goals_new").queryOrdered(byChild:"name").queryEqual(toValue: name)
    query.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

    //  if let values =
        if let values = snapshot.value as? [String:String] {
            print(values)
            print(values["name"]?.count ?? "")

        }
    }
```

**But I want to retrieve all the names in the database that matches the query**

Database Structure:

```
"goals_new" : [ null, {
    "name" : "Eric thomas",
    "pic" : “…….”,
    "title" : "Be Obsessed with your Goals",
    "url" : “……”
  }, 
{
    "name" : "Bob Proctor",
    "pic" : “……….",
    "title" : "Goal Achievement System",
    "url" : “………”
  },
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: At first glance your JSON, rules, and code all seem to match up. Are you sure you don't have another query somewhere that doesn't have the `goals_new` child?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, thanks for your response sorry about that. I updated my answer. I only have one query.

Comment: I honestly don't see what's going wrong in this code, the code you show is clearly querying `/goals_new`. I've never seen that warning point to a different path (`/` in your case) than what is actually being queried.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I am querying the /goals_new fine, but instead, I want to query the entire database from the root.

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding ".indexOn": "name" at / to your security rules <- Is only a warning so you don't have to worry much about that.

I'm seeing perhaps an error. Looks like you're using an array to store your objects of 'goals_news' because of the keys are numbers 1, 2, etc... Maybe that's is messing with your query, you have to change them for string keys like every time you add one use firebase method childByAutoID().

Better use .value instead of .childAdded method so you can get all the objects that matches the name, something like this:

```
      let query = ref.child("goals_new").queryOrdered(byChild:"name").queryEqual(toValue: name)
query.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

    guard snapshot.exists() && snapshot.hasChildren() else {return}
    for snap in snapshot.children {
          var currentSnapValue = (snap as! DataSnapshot).value as! [String: String]
         print("Name: \(currentSnapValue["name"])")

    }
 }
```

That way you're getting all the objects that matches the name

Comment: thanks for your response. This is only returning the names under the goals_new, but I want all the names in the database

Comment: @AbrahamEP: that warning is actually pretty bad. If you get it, the Firebase client will download all data from the server and perform the ordering/filtering in the client. The resulting functionality is the same, but you would be downloading way too much data.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, that's what I am trying to avoid doing. I dont want to download the entire database, just what's in the query